# What code in Python will save a file as a jpeg with RGB color mode and 300 dpi using Photoshop?

Tags: python-3.x, jpeg, photoshop

Here is my code I have so far.  It will open Photoshop and load the file I need and will save the jpeg but I want to make sure I tell it to save as the color mode RGB and 300 dpi.  What am I missing to be able to do that with this code:

This is the function:

```
def photoshop_image_convert(filepath,imageType,dotsPerInch,width,height):
    psApp = Dispatch('Photoshop.Application')
    psApp.Open(filepath)
    doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument
    doc.ResizeImage(Width=width, Height=height, Resolution=dotsPerInch)
    options = Dispatch('Photoshop.ExportOptionsSaveForWeb')
    options.Format = 6
    options.Quality = 100
    newFile = filepath + '.' + imageType
    doc.Export(ExportIn=newFile, ExportAs=2, Options=options)
```

This is the function call:

```
photoshop_image_convert(filepath,'jpg',300,2500,2500)
```

Comment: Why would youbother going to the cost and trouble of firing up Photoshop to save an image? Why not just use PIL? Or OpenCV? Or vips? Or ImageMagick/Wand?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell.  None of those Python libraries can open TIF files that have transparency backgrounds saved on them to do any kind of work on them.  They also create jpegs that produce a color difference.  Doing in Photoshop gives me an exact image of the TIF just in a jpeg format without issues.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing to be able to do that with this code...

**Check your original image's size**: Maybe it doesn't have enough pixels to fill 300 dots per inch in a 2500^2 [Unit] image.

You have 2500^2 = 6'250'000 = 6.25E6 [unit] in total.

Do you have at least 6.25E6 pixels in your original image?
Your image should be around 2741 by 2280 pixels.

Comment: it will make the resized original file 2500 x 2500 at 300 dpi but when I do the Export of the jpeg file it is 72dpi.  How do I save the jpeg out at 300 dpi with Python code?

Comment: What is the original size of your image (widthxheight)? Even if you "resize" the image, you might be upsampling. If you do so, Adobe may calculate the difference, lowering the DPI.

Comment: it could be different for all images that I work with.  In this particular case the one image is 2500 x 2012.

Comment: Try the following: photoshop_image_convert(
filepath, 'jpg', 300, 500, 500)

Comment: what will that do?  What if I have images that are bigger than that or does the 500, 500 always give me a jpeg with 2500 x 2500?

Comment: Either you have a problem with the jpeg. - or you have a problem with the fact that your image might be too small for 300dpi at 2500 by 2500. Out of curiosity, could you try the code above and tell me the output dpi? Also, how do you find this dpi? Do you re-open the fil in PS or use something else?

Comment: The output dpi is 72.  It didn't change the image size it is the original image size.  I open the jpeg in PS to see the dpi.